# Conditional Probability with coloured tokens

Tags: probability

Suppose that a friend gives us the chance to participate in a game. The game is as follows. There is a bucket
containing 25 green tokens and 10 red tokens. We are to blindly reach into the bucket and randomly choose one
token. Keeping this token (i.e. the chosen token is not returned to the bucket) we are to once again reach in
blindly and randomly retrieve another token. If both of the tokens we have chosen are green then we win the
game. Otherwise we lose. Define the two events below as follows:
• G1 = first token selected is green
• G2 = second token selected is green.

(a) What is P(G2|G1)?

(b) What is P(G1 and G2) = P(both tokens are green)?

(c) Using your answer from (b) above, is it more likely that we will win this game or lose this game? Explain.

Attempt: I've calculated P(G1) to be 1/35 and I believe P(G2) to be 1/34 since the first token has been removed however, i have a feeling that this is not correct and so the right answer may be 2/35 since 2 green tokens have been picked.

Comment: kindly include your thoughts and attempts.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

(a) It's clearly $24/34$ (Laplace Rule).

(b) You can use this useful identity,$$P(G2,G1)=P(G1)*P(G2|G1)$$
And $P(G1)=25/35$ (Laplace Rule again), so:
$$P(G2,G1)= \frac{25*24}{35*34}=0.504...$$

(c) Well it's more likely to win because the probability of winning it's more than $1/2$.

Comment: Isn't (a) 24/34? Now you get a different value for (b) and a different answer for (c), but I agree with your process.

Comment: Ooops, thought it was with reposition, editing